# Directive doesn't work in a sub module

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-module

I can't make the directive work in a lazy loaded module. I've read the documentation and I simply added the directive into declarations array of my main module. The directive works as expected at that module, but it doesn't work in lazy loaded modules. It even prevents lazy loaded module to be opened because of the template error:

```
Can't bind to 'myHighlight' since it isn't a known property of 'p'
```

Here's my [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/wvTnRIaL7N1D2SOPmwPA).

Check out errors in console after clicking 'go to child'

Comment: It is mentioned in documentation, but I don't understand as in main module, directive is well declared... https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html#!#your-directive-isn-t-working-

Comment: Clarify the problem, or may be it's another problem? When you post a link to the code make sure the problem code is accompanied the question.

Comment: @RomanC Sorry for poor explanation. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

That's because your directive is declared in `AppModule`and it's only available there. If you want to use directive in both modules, you can create `SharedModule` and then declare and export directive from there, and then import `SharedModule` in your `AppModule` and your `ChildModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ HighlightDirective ],
  exports: [ HighlightDirective ]
})

export class SharedModule {}
```

Now you just need to add `SharedModule` to `AppModule`'s and `ChildModule`'s imports.

**Note:**

You have to remove your directive from `AppModule`'s declarations since it can only be declared once.

Comment: But shouldn't the declarations declared in the AppModule be available globally throughout the app?

Comment: @echonax No, the only way to make anything globally available is the one I described, at least at this moment.

Answer (score 1):

I faced with similar problem in our project. I had shared.module but it still threw an error

> Can't bind to 'pathForUploading' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

I had this code

```
<div class="avatar"
     fileUploader
     [pathForUploading]="'path'"
     (onFileUploaded)="updateAvatar()"></div>
```

And it's gone after changing attribute calling to

```
pathForUploading="path"
```

Hope it will help somebody

Comment: I get `No provider for TemplateRef!` when I use it without the *