# How to communicate parent component interaction through child route component? (Angular2)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In the root component of the route configuration I have a button. When I click this button, I would like to trigger an event inside the activated child route.

I have been struggling with this for a while now, and the only thing that seems promising is using a [bi-directional service (link to angular docs)](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service). However, I'm not sure how to get it working.

Here is a plunk to demonstrate:

https://plnkr.co/edit/7zDTTTlABWD2GFo01jaz?p=preview

I've set up a simple route configuration which automatically redirects to the TestComponent. When I click on the 'click' button at the route app level, I would like to be able to trigger the `clickDetected()` function inside TestComponent.

Hope everything is clear - any advice is appreciated!

Code below;

---

app.component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <input type="button" (click)="onClick('hello')" value="click" />
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private testService: TestService) {
  }

  onClick(v){
    this.testService.declareClick(v)
  }
}
```

test.service

```
@Injectable()
export class TestService {

  private clickedSource = new Subject<string>();

  clicked$ = this.clickedSource.asObservable();

  declareClick(value: string) {
    console.log(value)
    return this.clickedSource.next(value);
  }

}
```

test.component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-test',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h1>Test Component</h1>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  public clicked?: any

  constructor(private testService: TestService) {
  }

  clickDetected(){
   console.log("parent clicked")
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.testService.declareClick()
/*      .subscribe((v) => {
        this.clicked? = v;
        console.log(v)
      })*/
  }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2: Parent and Child Components Communication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36316896/angular2-parent-and-child-components-communication)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to `.subscribe()` to the `Observable` that is receiving the `.next()` events:

```
this.testService.clickedSource.subscribe((val)=>{
  console.log(2, val);
});
```

Fixed Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/aPR6KvuOi2tgQXLgokHi?p=preview

Comment: Ahh very frustrating I was missing a small edit, thanks a lot for pointing out where I was going wrong! (will accept when timer allows)

Comment: Hmm.. I saw that error in my answer as well. I don't know why I didn't think you could access service provided in the parent module. My answer is still valid though and can still be useful in various other cases so.. I'll leave it there. :)

Comment: @echonax I'm trying to implement this solution with another level of routing, but I'm not able to subscribe to the observable? I tried to get a plunk up and running, but it was complicated to put a child routing system in for some reason.

Comment: @lolio as long as the service is in the main app.module's providers list you should be able to subscribe to it. Can you add more detail?

Comment: @echonax I have a main routing module, then child routing module. Inside the child routing module I'm putting the button in the root component. I cannot subscribe to the Subject in any of the components listed inside the child routing module below this root. Simplest explanation I can think to use is that it's the same as the current example except everything moves down one level, if you can envisage this. ( Sorry if it's not well written, perhaps I can try get a plunk working with an example of what I mean at the weekend )

Comment: @lolio hmm, I couldn't think of anything that wouldn't make it work. I'll be waiting for your plunker

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT -- DO NOT DO THIS --**

Thanks to @echonax, I learned that is actually an example of what you should **NOT** do. I came to actually help people and I ended up learning something. Please, refer to the angular2 doc on why you should NOT do this.

**END EDIT**

You can *also* do this using a Shared Module. You make a module that provide the test service and import both in AppModule and your routed module. You can then provide the same instance of the service to both component. I made you a plunkr from your code that show how it works.

If you want more information on SharedModule, check Angular2 doc.
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#shared-module

Edited your question plunkr.
https://plnkr.co/edit/SU8AT4

---

**Shared Module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { TestService } from './test.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [
    TestService
  ],
  exports: [ ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

**New AppModule**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TestComponent } from './test.component';
import { SharedModule } from './shared.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TestComponent
  ],
  providers: [ ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**New AppRoutingModule**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TestComponent }  from './test.component';
import { SharedModule } from './shared.module';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '',   redirectTo: 'test', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'test',  component: TestComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    SharedModule
  ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ],
  providers: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Be careful tho "_Do not specify app-wide singleton providers in a shared module. A lazy loaded module that imports that shared module will make its own copy of the service._" [@Angular2 SharedModule](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#why-_userservice_-isn-t-shared)

Comment: Hmm.. it seems that you're totally right. I made a big banner that people shouldn't do this. Should I leave it here as a counter-example of just delete it?

Comment: It is only an issue in lazy loaded modules. Your example works too so I don't see the harm as long as the warning is mentioned :-) It's also educational.

Comment: Fine.. It stays. I work with lazyLoaded featureModule right now and I think that might have been one of the issue I've been having. Will providing it in AppModule actually work in a lazyloaded module?

Comment: For providers: yes. For directives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41433766/directive-doesnt-work-in-a-sub-module

Comment: Note: you can still make a shared module work with lazy-loaded modules. They may warn against it in the docs, but they do it themselves for many modules. `@NgModule(...) export class SharedModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return { ngModule: SharedModule };
    }
}`; then just import the shared module with `SharedModule.forRoot()`