# Angular 2 - Error when try to import a component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

i have a project with this structure:

```
app
|
 |pages
    |Dashboard
        |Component1
    |UI
        |ModalComponent
```

I want to show a ModalComponent  on /Dashboard/Component1, but when I try it i have this error:

> No component factory found for DefaultModal. Did you add it to
>   @NgModule.entryComponents?

My dashboard.module.ts

```
import { PieChartService } from './pieChart/pieChart.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppTranslationModule,
    NgaModule,
    routing
  ],
  declarations: [
     PieChart,
     /..Some components../

],
  providers: [
    PieChartService,
    /..Some services../
  ]

})
export class DashboardModule {}
```

My modal.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule }  from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgbDropdownModule, NgbModalModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { DefaultModal } from './components/modals/default-modal.component';


    @NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    /.../
  ],
  declarations: [
    DefaultModal
  ],
  exports: [
    DefaultModal
  ]
})
export class UiModule {
}
```

What i'm doing wrong? Thanks

**Edit**

If i add `entryComponents: [DefaultModal]` in DashboardModule, the error changes to :

> Component DefaultModal is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.

Comment: Have you googled the error?

Comment: Yes, and see many solutions, but the error is maintained or a different one appears

Comment: What is `DefaultModal`? You don't seem to be importing it anywhere

Comment: I deleted the imports because otherwise the code is very long

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Directive doesn't work in a sub module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41433766/directive-doesnt-work-in-a-sub-module)

Comment: Can you check/try the link and share the results?

Comment: Very thankful. This solution work for me. I have to change some things but now all works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally all works thanks to @echonax [Directive doesn't work in a submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41433766/directive-doesnt-work-in-a-sub-module)

I have to change my principal module like this :

dashboard.module.ts

```
import { PieChartService } from './pieChart/pieChart.service';
import { UiModule } from './ui/ui.module'; //<====this line

@NgModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        AppTranslationModule,
        NgaModule,
        UiModule, //<====this line
        routing
      ],
      declarations: [
         PieChart,
     /..Some components../

],
  providers: [
    PieChartService,
    /..Some services../
  ]

})
export class DashboardModule {}
```

I have discovered that the modules work as "packages", and that if you declare several components in a module, when importing that module you bring the declaration of all those components, being able to use them without any problem.